# Eclipse won't launch

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

Eclipse has recently stopped working on my computer. I don't receive any error messages, double clicking on the shortcut does nothing. My OS is Windows 8.1 and my eclipse.ini file contains:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Have you installed/uninstalled java recently?

Comment: I recently installed NetBeans, Atom and Unreal Engine

Comment: Have you updated java to the latest version perhaps? Also, can you attempt to start from command line and see if there is an error?

Comment: Starting from the command line gives me 'Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', 'Error: could not find java.dll' and 'Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment'

Comment: Do you have execute permissions on the unzipped files?

Answer (score 1):

Please try cleaning your Eclipse install with the `-clean` parameter.

Open a console in your Eclipse directory, and run the following:

> eclipse.exe -clean

After running this, relaunch Eclipse normally.

You have also mentioned that you just installed Netbeans, this install may have updated your Java install, please also check your envirnomental variables for validity.

Your JRE / JDK directory should both be set in `JAVA_HOME` and your `PATH` variable. What evrsion of Eclipse are you running? (Current is Luna)

Comment: What did not work about it? Were any errors returned in the console? Or did it fail to execute?

Comment: Also, can you check your last-used workspace for any log-files that may have been created during the launch? If they exist, they will be located at >`/last_workspace/.metadata/.log`

Comment: No errors were returned in the console and it still won't open

Comment: By default, directories that begin with a `.` are hidden. You may have to enable hidden files, or explicitly specify the directory. If eclipse created a workspace folder, then there is absolutely a `.metadata` folder within.

Comment: I'm getting these 3 errors when running "java -version" on the console.  'Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', 'Error: could not find java.dll' and 'Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment'

Comment: Check your `Environment Variables` and ensure that `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly to the path of the latest install JRE. The variable should have a value similar to this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31`, changing depending on your install location.

Comment: I re-installed Java and it's working again. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Glad you are back up and running. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you alt-tabbed often enough ? if eclipse is in the background and not focused the splash screen with the eclipse logo can hide the "choose-workspace-dialog"

eclipse won't do anything until you have choosen a workspace

Comment: Tried that, nothing comes up.

Comment: have you deleted your workspace folder recently ? or moved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your eclipse can't run on java 8. (What's your eclipse version?) Try uninstalling java 8 to test that or just alter the PATH to point to java 7.